# Многопоточностью Невозможно вычислить выражение, поскольку код оптимизирован или машинный фрейм находится на вершине стека вызовов. string

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Доброго времени суток, пишу многопоточный сканер сети на наличии сайта на том или ином ip. Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
При <20 потоках полет нормальный, со своими функциями справляется, но если выставить к примеру 500 потоков, то сайт пропускается. Конкретнее: на неком ip есть сайт, который находится под shared hosting, что бы его достать необходимо установить заголовку "Host" значения домена этого сайта.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int count = 0;
    static string toFind;
    bool done=false;
    bool work = false;
    string Host;
    int w8;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!work)
        {
            try
            {
                var FileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
                if (FileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    MainVar.ip.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(FileDialog.FileName));
                    if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "")
                    {
                        toFind = textBox1.Text;
                        Host = textBox2.Text;
                        w8 = Convert.ToInt32(TimeOut.Value);
                        done = false;
                        work = true;
                        DoFind();
                        button1.Text = "Stop";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Enter key and domen!");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
             else
                {
            //остановка
                    work = false;
                    button1.Text = "Start";
                    done = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Wait while stopping");
                }
    }

    //запуск потоков
    public  void DoFind()
    {
       for (int i = 0; (i<= numThread.Value && i<MainVar.ip.Count); i++)
        {
            Thread th = new Thread(Connect);
            th.IsBackground = true;
            th.Start();
            MainVar.thread.Add(th);
        }
    }

    //выборка диапазона из коллекции
    public  IPAddressCollection  GiveIp()
    {
        lock (MainVar.ip) {
            if (MainVar.ip.Count != 0)
            {
                IPNetwork ip = IPNetwork.Parse(MainVar.ip[0]);
                IPAddressCollection ipcol = IPNetwork.ListIPAddress(ip);
                MainVar.ip.RemoveAt(0);
                return ipcol;
            } else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    //проверка ip
    public void Connect()
    {
        while (MainVar.ip.Count!=0)
        {
            IPAddressCollection ipcol = GiveIp();

        if (ipcol != null && !done)
        {   
                            var request = new HttpRequest();
                            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                            request.UserAgent = Http.FirefoxUserAgent(); ;
                            request.Referer = "https://mail.ru/";
                            request.ConnectTimeout = w8;
                            request.Cookies = new CookieDictionary();
                            request.Host = Host;

            for (int i = 0; i < ipcol.Count; i++)
            {
                try
               {
                        string z = request.Post("http://" + ipcol[i] + "/").ToString();
                        count++;//счетчик
                        stat();//передача в основной поток

                    //поиск нужного сайта
                    if (z.Contains(toFind))
                    {
                            MessageBox.Show("Find:" + ipcol[i]);
                            WriteIp(ipcol[i].ToString());
                    }  
               }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                       // MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                        count++;//счетчик
                        stat();//передача в основной поток
                           //остановка потоков
                    if (done)
                    {
                        done = false;
                        foreach (var thr in MainVar.thread)
                        {
                            if (thr.Name != Thread.CurrentThread.Name)
                            {
                                thr.Abort();
                            }
                        }

                        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else//if(ipcol!= null && !done)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
        }

    }
        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
    }

    public void WriteIp(string ip)
    {
        File.AppendAllText("Found.txt", ip + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void stat()
    {
        try
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                label2.Text = count.ToString();
            }));
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

При небольшом кол-ве потоков проблем не возникает, однако при +-500 этот ip пролетает как пустой, в режиме отладки выявляется следующие проблемы
[image: Невозможно вычислить выражение, поскольку код оптимизирован или машинный фрейм находится на вершине стека вызовов.]

Ввиду того что заголовок Host не принимает значение - сайт пропускается, не подскажите как с этим бороться?

Comment: Используйте async/await. 500 потоков -- это очень много.

Comment: Предположу, что какой-то кусок кода заинлайнился, поэтому он не существует в виде отдельного вызова

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась увеличением объема стека, всем спасибо за помощь.